# React router dom v6 state issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I migrated from router v5 to 6, and I am not sure if that or something along the way caused, that my on button click routing doesn't update the state anymore. Maybe some advice if it works a little different now or what could be the issue?

Here is my button:

```
<Button
          onClick={() => {
            navigate('/componentB', {
              state: {
                filters: [
                  {
                    name: 'id',
                    value: rowData.id,
                  },
                ],
              },
            });
          }}
        >
          Button
</Button>
```

rowData is coming from the renderer, that part works fine...

and here is my network request payload:

```
{
    "filters": [],
}
```

It redirects, but the state is not updating.
What could be the problem?

BTW my v5 working implementation:

```
<Button
      history.push({
              pathname: '/componentB',
              state: {
                filters: [
                  {
                    name: 'id',
                    value: rowData.id,
                  },
                ],
              },
            });
          }}
        >
          Button
</Button>
```